# Iniciar e Derrubar banco em teste flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

Estou fazendo um test de api, que eu passo um json ele me valida se voltou tudo ok:

minha classe base:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# base.py

import os
import unittest
from app import initialize
from mock import mock
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import database
os.environ = {
    my_variavels:
}

test_app = Flask(__name__)
test_app.config.from_object('app.config.TestingConfig')
database.AppRepository.db = SQLAlchemy(test_app)

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    mock = mock
    user = initialize.web_app.test_client()
```

acredito que nesse arquivo base, deveria ter as funcoes teardown, Setup etc..

```
 json_gardener = {"id": "1",
                    "name": "Jamme"}
```

E tenho a seguinte função que faz o post nesse caso:

```
def test_post_gardener(self):
             response = self.user.post('/gardeners', headers={'VALIDATION': 'XXXX'}, data=self.json_gardener)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Até ai tudo ok, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando vou rodar a segunda vez obviamente ele vai que já existe o id no banco e vai dar erro.

Minha duvida a seguinte, existe um jeito de subir um banco de dados para test e quando terminar de executar ele desmontar?

Comment: Como está sua estrutura de testes? Sugiro você utilizar o unittest com um banco de dados como o sqlite, e no unittest há o método de classe tearDown() que é executado no final da execução , assim, poderia ter um rotina para limpar o banco. Poderia dar mais detalhes?

Comment: estou usando o nosetest, banco postgres pode me falar mais do metodo teardown, e como inicio o banco?

Comment: Se o banco é de testes, você não pode só mandar um ``DELETE`` pra ``API`` e apagar o registro? Ainda testa o método ``DELETE`` da aplicação. A menos que você use ele pra desativar o cara, aí realmente é melhor ter uma função de limpeza dos testes que só dá ``TRUNCATE`` nas tabelas mesmo.

Comment: Está usando classes ou somente métodos isolados?

Comment: classe, após o almoçou vou detalhar melhor a pergunta

Comment: Resolveu? O problema..

Comment: Negativo, adicionei mais informacoes na pergunta

Comment: Faz parte da regra gerar o id na camada de aplicação e não com um sequencial no banco? Ou você simplesmente está fazendo isso no Feed do metodo de teste para poder testar o ID já tendo o valor anteriormente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a própria documentação do Flask há a classe `tempfile` que pode ser usada para isto como instância de banco de dados na classe de teste.

```
import os
import flaskr
import unittest
import tempfile

class FlaskrTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.db_fd, flaskr.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
        flaskr.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = flaskr.app.test_client()
        with flaskr.app.app_context():
            flaskr.init_db()

    def tearDown(self):
        os.close(self.db_fd)
        os.unlink(flaskr.app.config['DATABASE'])

    def test_empty_db(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/')
        assert b'No entries here so far' in rv.data

    def login(self, username, password):
    return self.app.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)

    def logout(self):
        return self.app.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)

    def test_login_logout(self):
        rv = self.login('admin', 'default')
        assert b'You were logged in' in rv.data
        rv = self.logout()
        assert b'You were logged out' in rv.data
        rv = self.login('adminx', 'default')
        assert b'Invalid username' in rv.data
        rv = self.login('admin', 'defaultx')
        assert b'Invalid password' in rv.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Fonte: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/